# How to make sure not to mention confidential information in your cv

Tags: resume, applications, position

When mentioning a job position in industry on your cv, how much information can you give about the job content?

- First example:

  > [Job title] at [Company]: performing mechanical simulations

This description does not seem to disclose confidential information, but it is too general.

- Second example:

  > [Job title] at [Company]: performing mechanical simulations for the design of new aircraft wing structures.

Although this discription does not give too many details about the 'new aircraft wing structures', it still discloses that the company did/is still doing research/development in this domain.

Note that it is often not desiderable to talk with your boss or colleagues about which information to put in your cv if you are planning to leave your current position.

So how can I know that I do not mention confidential information in my cv?

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Why is the first too general? Do you only do wings?

Comment: is this a job with security clearance ?- that makes a big diference

Comment: I believe that the very first thing you need to be very clear on what about your job is actually confidential.

Comment: If the information has ever been issued in a press release or on the company's web site, it's not confidential.  Otherwise, assume it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ask your current boss what you can and can't say about the job. You don't have to say you're asking for CV purposes; this is something you should know before describing your job to *anyone*, including friends, relatives, the guy or gal you're trying to chat up at the party.. Or even with coworkers when you're someplace where non-employees could overhear the conversation.

The company undoubtedly has policies which cover that.

CV has to respect the same rules.

Comment: Also, some NDA's have a time limit on the information. So some information can be disclosed after x amounts of years. This could be useful in case you wish to update your CV in several years with more accurate information about the company.